# Strange ios 5 error in addressbook

Tags: ios5, abaddressbook

I have done the following to get record for user info from address book.

```
- (ABRecordRef)findRecordNSString *)phoneNumber
{
if (phoneNumber == nil)
return nil;
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

CFArrayRef all = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

CFIndex n = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

ABRecordRef record;

//NSLog(@"The Record : %d", record);

int count = 0;

for( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
{
ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(all, i);

ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
for(CFIndex j = 0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); j++)
{

CFStringRef phoneNumberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, j);

NSString *newPhoneNumber = (NSString *)phoneNumberRef;



if([newPhoneNumber isEqualToStringhoneNumber])
{
//NSLog(@"Phone Ref: %@", phoneNumberRef);
NSLog(@"Record New: %d", ref);
record = ref;

i=(int)n;
count = 1;
}
CFRelease(phoneNumberRef);
[newPhoneNumber release];
}

}
[addressBook release];
return record;
}
```

but i am getting an error when I try to open the viewController in ios5 device but it works in simulator and ios 4.
the error is

```
Program received signal: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Can't find dlopen function, so it is not possible to load shared libraries.)
```

Also after this error if I forcefully clos the app by double tapping home button and then quit manually the app will only show a black screen. Any idea regarding this?

Comment: I am getting a very similar error. It works in the developer when run in 4.3 but crashes on 5.0.

Comment: @logixologist I have resolved this issue. If you need help let me know

Comment: @RahulVyas perhaps you can answer your own question. It is showing up as Unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just commented the line

```
CFIndex n = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);
```

And replaced with this to get total number of records

```
CFIndex n = CFArrayGetCount(all);
```

Because the count is different for all(Array) and for the variable n.

Hope this will help others too.